# Extending $\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}\frac{1}{n^s}$ without analytic continuation

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence

For real $s>1$,
the series $\alpha(s):=\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}\frac{1}{n^s}$
converges.
The Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ is formed by analytic continuation of $\alpha(s)$
to $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus\{1\}$.
We do this because,
in complex analysis, $\alpha(s)$ diverges outside of its defined domain, but I wonder if there is some more arithmetic and less analytical sense by which it extends to (at least some maximal subset of) $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus\{1\}$.

For example, following [Ramanujan's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Heuristics), we can compute that
$$\alpha(-1)(=1+2+3+\dots)=-\frac{1}{12}$$
using nothing other than a power series and come clever manipulation,
even though complex analysis will tell you that series diverges.

I especially wonder about the trivial zeros of $\zeta$. Is there some sense by which it is equally (maybe more) "trivial" that $\alpha(s)=0\ \forall s\in-2\mathbb{N}$.
For instance, is there some simple clever proof I've never seen showing that $$1+2+4+9+16+\dots=0?$$

Lastly, I wonder what it is about the harmonic series that makes it so badly behaved. We can find a sense by which (some extension of) these series $\alpha(s)$ converge for every single $s$-value in the complex plane except for $\alpha(1)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots$.

Comment: Have you seen the proof given by Helmut Hasse in the 1930ies or so? I think it builded on an idea of Konrad Knopp earlier or possibly even older, using a binomial composition, much related to Euler-summation. (H.Hasse, 1930 "Ein Summierungsverfahren für die Riemann'sche Zeta-Reihe" online, digicenter Göttingen, don't remember the actual math journal, though...)

Comment: @HelmutHasse I don't understand German, but would be willing to try. Which part does he prove?

Comment: Let's see tomorrow, it is after midnight here...

Comment: To see a much amateurish old explanation of Hasse's ide you might look at the beginning of http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/10_2_recihasse.pdf where I try to apply his idea to another case. I expressed all such things like summation-procedures by matrix-notations which likely should explained more themselves, but you might get Hasse's basic idea. For his actual proof he used then integral-expressions and exp-function, something I couldn't reproduce with my small exploratory matrix-toolbox... If needed I can possibly come back to this tomorrow.

Comment: Once you know the RHS of $(1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s)= \lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}e^{-nx}$ is analytic you obtain $(1-2^{1+k})\zeta(-k) $ as the $k$-th derivative of $\frac{-1}{e^x+1}$ and since $\frac{1}{e^x+1}-\frac12$ is odd you get $\zeta(-2k)=0$

Comment: @reuns Okay, that seems like a better reason than I was thinking for those zeros to be called "trivial."

Comment: @j0equ1nn (I meant $\lim_{x \to 0}$)

Comment: FYI: If I get no actual answers and 0 upvotes, I will conclude that this question does not really interest anyone, take some notes on the comments, and delete it